# Use GitHub Releases with Esky

Tags: python, git, github, esky

Is it possible to use the github releases as a sever to host updates that esky can use? And if yes, how do I implement this especially with regards to the url I provide to the

```
updater = esky.Esky(sys.executable, "http://localhost:8000")
```

command? Or do I have to host my releases somewhere else, and if that is the case, does anybody have any suggestions (preferably at no cost).

Answer (score 1):

The default Esky finder needs a directory to look in. You could extend it to look in and download from github releases.

I have had success with using [Github pages](https://pages.github.com/) to serve my static files.

For a github user of `linus` and project `linux` in a folder `_downloads`.
Point esky to the following:
https://github.com/Linus/Linux/tree/gh-pages/_downloads`